# How to call in grails framework one class method to another class method?

Tags: grails

How to call in grails framework one class method to another class method? example...

```
class ChartClassController {

    def index() {}

    def create(){
        def chartClassTypeList = ChartClassType.list()
    }
}

class ChartGroupController {

    def index() {}

    def create(){
        def chartGroupTypeList = ChartGroupType.list()
    }
}
```

I just call class (ChartGroupController) method (create) in ChartClassController ?? How is it possible ?? NEED A HELP !!

Answer (score 4):

Controllers aren't regular classes, they're basically event handlers responding to requests. The life cycle is managed by Grails and Spring, and they're basically not directly callable.

Rather than calling one controller from another, consider moving the logic from that method that you want in both controllers to a utility class under src/groovy. Then call it from the two controllers.

Another option would be to create a base class that both controllers extend, and put that shared logic in a base class method that both controllers call from their create methods.

Comment: Yes! i know,Thank you! brother..:) but is it not possible? if i import the ChartGroupController in ChartClassController!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a redirect (whether it makes sense from a user perspective is debatable):

```
def create(){
    redirect(class:"ChartGroupController", action:"create")
}
```

Also, there is nothing to stop you from simply calling **any** domain class in **any** controller, so your `ChartClassController` could have:

```
def create(){
    def chartGroupTypeList = ChartGroupType.list()
}
```

and you could even use a view from your `ChartGroup` directory if you wished. But you probably want to keep your "domains" separated for simplicity and readability.